# Python for loop within function not returning values

Tags: python, for-loop

I wrote this fairly simple Python function but for some reason after the for loop ends, nothing returns or is able to be printed out within the function. I can call the function just fine and I called prints within the for loop to ensure the values were correct and they were. Am I missing anything obvious here? The print statement at the bottom prints nothing.

```
def evaluate_arima_model(X, arima_order, s_arima_order):
    scores = []
    train_steps = [36, 48, 60, 72, 84]
    for i in train_steps:
        Train = X[0:i]
        Test = X[i:i + 12]
        model = SARIMAX(Train, order=arima_order, seasonal_order=s_arima_order)
        model_fit = model.fit(trend='nc', disp=0)
        yhat = model_fit.forecast(12)
        rmse = sqrt(mean_squared_error(numpy.exp(Test), numpy.exp(yhat)))
        scores.append(rmse)
    print(scores)
    return scores
```

This is how the function is called (by another function with nested loops

```
def evaluate_models(dataset, p_values, d_values, q_values, sp_values, sd_values, sq_values, s_values):
dataset = dataset.astype('float32')
best_score, best_cfg, best_cfg2 = float("inf"), None, None 
for p in p_values:
    for d in d_values:
        for q in q_values:
            order = (p,d,q)
            for sp in sp_values:
                for sd in sd_values:
                    for sq in sq_values:
                        for s in s_values:
                            sorder = (sp,sd,sq,s)
                            try:
                                rmse = evaluate_arima_model(dataset, order, sorder)
                                if rmse < best_score:
                                    best_score, best_cfg, best_cfg2 = rmse, order, sorder
                                print('ARIMA%s SARIMA%s RMSE=%.3f' % (order,sorder,rmse))
                            except:
                                continue
print('\n','Best ARIMA%s SARIMA%s RMSE=%.3f' % (best_cfg, best_cfg2, best_score))


series = read_csv('dataset.csv', header=None, index_col=0, parse_dates=True, squeeze=True)
series = numpy.log(series)

# Evaluate parameters
p_values = range(0, 2)
d_values = range(0, 2)
q_values = range(0, 2)

# Evaluate seasonal parameters
sp_values = range(0, 2)
sd_values = range(0, 2)
sq_values = range(0, 2)

#Set seasonality
s_values = [12]

#Call grid loop
evaluate_models(series, p_values, d_values, q_values, sp_values, sd_values, sq_values, s_values)
```

**Output:** Best ARIMANone SARIMANone RMSE=inf

**New version still not working:**

```
def evaluate_arima_model(X, arima_order, s_arima_order):
scores = []
train_steps = [36, 48, 60, 72, 84]
for i in train_steps:
    Train = X[0:i]
    Test = X[i:i + 12]
    model = SARIMAX(Train, order=arima_order, seasonal_order=s_arima_order)
    model_fit = model.fit(trend='nc', disp=0)
    yhat = model_fit.forecast(12)
    rmse = None
    rmse = sqrt(mean_squared_error(numpy.exp(Test), numpy.exp(yhat)))
    scores.append(rmse)
    print(scores)
print(scores)
return scores
```

Comment: Does it print _nothing_ or `[]`?

Comment: printing is not returning. You mean you've assigned the result of your function and it's  `None` ?

Comment: So, since we can't reproduce it. What is shown with the different prints you did? i.e. this "I can call the function just fine and I called prints within the for loop to ensure the values were correct and they were."

Comment: nothing prints out at all

Comment: Adding a return still doesn't make it return anything sadly. I would expect that print to run even with no return though, yes?

Comment: Can you add the output in the question?

Comment: added output and full logic of the functions called

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Finally sorted this out, the issue was returning a list vs a scalar, which is what I needed. So "return scores[0]" fixed it.

```
def evaluate_arima_model(X, arima_order, s_arima_order):
    scores = []
    train_steps = [36]
    for i in train_steps:
        Train = X[0:i]
        Test = X[i:i + 12]
        model = SARIMAX(Train, order=arima_order, seasonal_order=s_arima_order)
        model_fit = model.fit(trend='nc', disp=0)
        yhat = model_fit.forecast(12)
        rmse = sqrt(mean_squared_error(numpy.exp(Test), numpy.exp(yhat)))
        scores.append(rmse)
    return scores[0]
```

Answer (score 2):

Your `print()` statement *must* *print* something. However, because you do not have a `return` statement, your function does not return anything (well, it returns `None`). If you want your function to return something, add one last line:

```
return scores
```

---

#### DEBUG ATTEMPT:

Simplify code:

```
In [1]: def evaluate_arima_model(X, arima_order, s_arima_order):
   ...:     scores = []
   ...:     train_steps = [36, 48, 60, 72, 84]
   ...:     for i in train_steps:
   ...:         rmse = None
   ...:         scores.append(rmse)
   ...:     print(scores)
   ...:     return scores
   ...: 
   ...: 

In [2]: evaluate_arima_model(1,1,1)
[None, None, None, None, None]
Out[2]: [None, None, None, None, None]
```

I do not see a reason for this to not work.

Comment: it should at least print the scores, even if  there is no return statement, because of `print(scores)`

Comment: @WaleedIqbal Yes, it should. And I do not see why it wouldn't print. It _has to_!

Comment: Yeah that's what I'm not getting. I expect that print to run. Adding the return doesn't help anyway

Comment: @bhat557 See my edit. There is no way it does not work. Most likely the code that you posted is not the same as the code that you are running.

Comment: Okay the nones do print out now. Any reason why they wouldn't before?

Comment: @bhat557 I have no idea why it was not working before, but I strongly suspect that the example that you posted is not the same as your actual code because there is no logical reason for your example not to work.

Comment: Hmm, I mean I definitely copied/pasted it. So I ran your snippet line for line and it works but when I slightly modify it (see updated question at the bottom), the outer print statement prints nothing again (the one within the loop prints out correct values though).

Answer (score 0):

You need to write the return statement instead of print.

```
def evaluate_arima_model(X, arima_order, s_arima_order):
    scores = []
    train_steps = [36, 48, 60, 72, 84]
    for i in train_steps:
        Train = X[0:i]
        Test = X[i:i + 12]
        model = SARIMAX(Train, order=arima_order, seasonal_order=s_arima_order)
        model_fit = model.fit(trend='nc', disp=0)
        yhat = model_fit.forecast(12)
        rmse = sqrt(mean_squared_error(numpy.exp(Test), numpy.exp(yhat)))
        scores.append(rmse)
    return(scores)
```

Comment: there is no `println` in python.

Comment: @WaleedIqbal edited actually I use more of Scala syntax so sorry for the typo.